# Iterate through a map of interface that contains different levels of maps

Tags: dictionary, go, interface, range, slice

So lets say I have a map of interface like this:

```
c := map[string]interface{} {
    "test":    test,
    "test2":   test2,
}
```

Assuming that `test` is a `map[string]map[string]map[string]string` and `test2` is `map[string]string`.

How would I create a for loop that would enumerate each index of the map and would enumerate through each index's map also?

So far I have gotten:

```
func sanitize_map(m map[string]interface{}) map[string]interface{} {
    for k, v := range m {
    //Here is where I want to enumerate through the map of k
    }
    return m
}
```

Comment: I don't quite get your question. Do you want to get a list of all keys in all maps, list of values, or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for reflection; use a [type assertion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) and pass the value back to your sanitize function

```
func sanitizeMap(m map[string]interface{}) map[string]interface{} {
    for k, v := range m {
        _ = k
        if v, ok := v.(map[string]interface{}); ok {
            sanitizeMap(v)
        }
    }
    return m
}
```

Comment: Your solution will fail at the end of recursion, when `v` is not a map.  With recursion, you always need a terminating condition.

Comment: I see you use type assertion failure to end the recursion. OK, scratch my last comment. I thought OP may want to do something special when `v` is an atom.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflect:

```
import "reflect"

func sanitize_map(m map[string]interface{}) map[string]interface{} {
    for k, v := range m {
        // Do something with the key k
        kind := reflect.ValueOf(v).Kind()
        if kind == reflect.Map {
             // You have to be sure the value is of type map[string]interface{}
             newValue := v.(map[string]interface{})
             // recursively call sanitize
             sanitize_map(newValue)
        }
    }
    return m
}
```

The carveat is: every value in the map has to be either **not** a `map` (atom) or a `map[string]interface{}`. Note `map[string]interface{}` and `map[string]map[string]interface{}` are completely unrelated types, and you cannot use a type assertion of the second type on the first one.

However, you can put a `map[string]map[string]string` in a `map[string]interface{}`, like this:

```
innerMap1 := make(map[string]interface{})
// map to strings
innerMap1["a"] = "String 1"
innerMap2 := make(map[string]interface{})
// set mappings, maybe to other types

outerMap := make(map[string]interface{})
outerMap["ABC"] = innerMap1
outerMap["DEF"] = innerMap2
```

Now you can pass outerMap to the function, and reflect will automatically "strip" the layers of maps for you.

Comment: You're making things slower by using reflect, and still have a type assertion that might panic. If you know the type, skip the reflection altogether.